# pgfplots- Adding a mark at the origin

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, nodes

I'm trying to show the beginning of a sketch of the graph y=xe^x, and this is what I have:

```
    \documentclass[10pt]{article}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usepackage{pgfplots}
    \usetikzlibrary{arrows}

    \begin{document}

    \begin{figure}
       \begin{tikzpicture}

  %draw and label axis
    \draw[->] (-4.3,0) -- (4.3,0) node[right] {$x$};
    \draw[->] (0,-4.3) -- (0,4.3) node[above] {$y$};

  \draw[smooth,samples=100,domain=-4:-2.5] plot(\x,{\x*exp(\x)}) ;

  \draw[smooth,samples=100,domain=0.8:1] plot(\x,{\x*exp(\x)}) ; 

       \end{tikzpicture}

  \label{figure 1:} \caption{\label{fig:I1f010}Beginning a sketch of $y=xe^x$.}

   \end{figure}
  \end{document}
```

This gives me the plot I want, but I would like to add an unlabelled point (black, and filled in) at the origin. How could I do this?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. Also thanks for the nice minimal working example. Unfortunately this does not contain any `pgfplots` code yet, so it might be a bit difficult to understand where exactly `pgfplots` comes into play here.

Answer (score 2):

This is straight forward. Add

```
\draw[fill] (0,0) circle[radius=2pt];
```

to your code.

```
    \documentclass[10pt]{article}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usepackage{pgfplots}
    \usetikzlibrary{arrows}

    \begin{document}

    \begin{figure}
       \begin{tikzpicture}

  %draw and label axis
    \draw[->] (-4.3,0) -- (4.3,0) node[right] {$x$};
    \draw[->] (0,-4.3) -- (0,4.3) node[above] {$y$};

  \draw[smooth,samples=100,domain=-4:-2.5] plot(\x,{\x*exp(\x)}) ;

  \draw[smooth,samples=100,domain=0.8:1] plot(\x,{\x*exp(\x)}) ;
  \draw[fill] (0,0) circle[radius=2pt];    %% this is added.
       \end{tikzpicture}

  \label{figure 1:} \caption{\label{fig:I1f010}Beginning a sketch of $y=xe^x$.}

   \end{figure}
  \end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here is a start, but try to read some pages from the `pgfplots`'s manual.

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[%
xmax=2,
xmin=-2,
ymin=-2,
ymax=2,
axis x line=center,
axis y line=center]

\addplot[blue, domain=-2:1] {x*exp(x)};

\node[below left] at (axis cs:0,0) {\footnotesize $0$};

\fill (axis cs:0,0) circle (2pt);
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```